# Local webservice can not connect to android emulator

Tags: c#, android, web-services, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

i use vs2015 , webapi web service and xamarin.Android

i create a solution with 2 projects

1- project is web Api
2- is xamarin.android project

in Web API project i have a Url (http://localhost:27635/api/books/1/details)
and this return details of book like this

```
{"query":{"Title":"Midnight Rain","Genre":"Fantasy","PublishDate":"2000-12-16T00:00:00","Description":"A former architect battles an evil sorceress.","Price":14.95,"Author":"Ralls, Kim"}}
"}
```

and in xamarin project:
I used this code for consuming web api project
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

   :
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.getWeatherButton);

        // When the user clicks the button ...
        button.Click += async (sender, e) => {

            // Get the latitude and longitude entered by the user and create a query.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080/api/books/1/details";
            //string url = "http://169.254.129.9/api/books/1/details";

            // Fetch the information asynchronously, 
            // parse the results, then update the screen:
            JsonValue json = await FetchWeatherAsync(url);
            ParseAndDisplay(json);
        };
    }
    // Gets data from the passed URL.
    private async Task<JsonValue> FetchWeatherAsync(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:


                   JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

                    // Return the JSON document:
                    return jsonDoc;

                }
            }
        }
        // Parse the weather data, then write temperature, humidity, 
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
        {
            TextView location = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.locationText);


            JsonValue weatherResults = json["query"];


            location.Text = weatherResults["Title"];

        }
    }
```

When I use my local webapi project , Below code will not be executed and Local webservice can not connect to android emulator for get data from web service, and get me a error

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
 // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
 JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());
// Return the JSON document:
return jsonDoc;
}
```

But,When I use an external web api is working correctly

Comment: use your real IP instead of localhost

Comment: i test it but not work  'string url = "http://169.254.129.9/api/books/1/details";' and '//string url = "http://169.254.129.9:8080/api/books/1/details";' and '//string url = "http://10.0.0.2/api/books/1/details";','//string url = "http://10.0.2.3/api/books/1/details";' doesn't work

Comment: why you had not included port ?

Comment: `http://168.192.1.100:8080` and other ip doesn't work too